# DataTables Change the order of columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I am printing to table with datatable colums with my order but the data table change the order, what can I do to abort that.

My code

```
                        $(document).ready( function () {
                                    $('#example').DataTable();
                                } );
                            </script>
```

Comment: Code shown won't change any column order. Provide a ***runnable*** [mcve] that reproduces problem

Answer (score 3):

If you want to disable sort globally you can use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dTable').dataTable( 
         {
         "bSort" : false
         } 
    );
});
```

Or if you want to set a default sort column back to what it was in the backend:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#dTable').DataTable( {
          "order": [[ 3, "desc" ]]
      } );
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution for your problem, use bsort attribute of DataTables plugin to disable default sorting

```js
$(function(){
    $("#example").dataTable({
      "bSort" : false
    });
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="example">
    <thead>
      <tr><th>Sites</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>SitePoint</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Learnable</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Flippa</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Hope it helps you to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  $('#example').DataTable({
   ...,
   order: [0, 'asc'],
   ...
   });
} );
```

or arrange the list descended by putting 'desc' instead of 'asc'.
The first value in array assigned by key 'order' is column index.
for your possible first column 'id' it is 0.

And you are done.